# How to remove a key from a session in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How can I remove key from a Mojolicious session? 
I have hash reference `$orders` in session:

```
my $orders = $self->session('orders');
$orders->{a} = 1;
#some work with $orders;
```

Comment: And what is it that you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the hash element `$orders->{a}` then you need to use `delete`

```
delete $orders->{a}
```

Anything else, such as `$orders->{a} = undef` will leave the element in place but with a value of `undef`

Answer (score 0):

For GET/POST I would use:

```
$self->req->url->query->remove('orders');
```

How about

```
$self->session->remove('orders');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just delete as usual you do in perl:

`delete $orders->{a};
delete $c->session->{orders};
delete $c->session->{orders}{a};`

Based on [this](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Controller#session)